# Failure to export the data frame into CSV

Tags: r, dataframe, export-to-csv

Please, I don't know why it always fails when I save my work:

```
#menentukan tempat penyimpanan
setwd("C:/Users/Child-PC/Documents/Doc/Kerja/Jakarta Smart City/Data/CRM/CRM (Files) Mei 2019/R Function")

#menyimpan data ke csv
write.csv(nilai_data, file="nilai_data.csv")
```

The error message thrown is below:

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object file name' not found

Comment: You change directory then save the file. Is the file in that directory?

Comment: Is your path actually valid? Is nilai_data a suitable format (data frame, or matrix) ?  Can you save a different object there? e.g.   test <- 'mytest' ; write.csv(test, 'nilai_data_test.csv')

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to save a non-existing `data.frame`. Please see simulation below for non-existing data.frame:

```
# nilai_data_test - is not existing because of a wrong name or a typo
exists("nilai_data_test")
# [1] FALSE
# confirmed, it does not exist   
write.csv(nilai_data_test, file="nilai_data.csv")
```

Throws an error:

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'nilai_data_test' not found.

Basically the recomendation is that before exporting the data frame to csv-file it is better to create it and/or check the spelling of data frame's name.